# How to manage connexion with IndexedDb in Single Page Application

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I'm trying to understand how to work properly with IndexedDb and one thing I can't understand is how are we supposed to manage the connection.

When I started playing with IndexedDb, I created a connection once the page is loaded and let it open. So the same connection was used with every request to the database until the page was reloaded.

Letting a connection open seemed like a bad practice (which is what I want to confirm) so I changed my code to open the connection only when needed (when retrieving data for example) and close it immediately after.
It doesn't feel like the API was supposed to be used that way as I felt like fighting it when modifying my code (which might simply be because I have not yet fully understood how to work with it).

Can someone please explain to me the best practice when working with IndexedDb ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really have a best practice about it, but when you are working with databases on a server you mostly close the connection when the action is completed, and you open one for every action you want to do. In the library I builded to wrap the indexedDB I also choose to open and close the db connection for every action. That way I'm sure that no connections stay open, and it gives me the flexibility to change the db structure without having to worry about all the open connections.

What are the issues you are suffering with when opening and closing the db connection for every call?

Comment: I agree with your point on leaving a connection open on a server is not a good practice. With IndexedDb, we work on a html page so I thought the requirement might be different. The issues I have with "opening and closing the db connection for every call" is all the callback to manage for connexion and the request. I have not yet worked with schema update and transaction which might make things a lot more complex.

Comment: I use promises to handle all the async work. Here (http://linq2indexeddb.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Linq2IndexedDB/Linq2IndexedDB/Source/Core.js) you can see how I manage it. Another reason not to leave the connection open is the fact that everytime the user opens an additional tab/page an extra connection is made.